# how to configure a maven project to read from a config.properties file?

Tags: java, maven, properties, pom.xml

I have a servlet with a DAO class which has the following constructor:

```
public DAO() {
   env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
   env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
   env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://localhost:1389");
   env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
   env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=Directory Manager");
   env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "secret");
}
```

I've written the following config.properties file in source/main/resources :

```
 INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory
 PROVIDER_URL=ldap://localhost:1389
 SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION=simple
 SECURITY_PRINCIPAL=cn=Directory Manager
 SECURITY_CREDENTIALS=secret
```

How do I configure the pom.xml file to tell maven to use config.properties ?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html

Check some examples / tutorials for that ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here, I resolved adding the plugin block:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
      <executions>
       <execution>
        <phase>initialize</phase>
         <goals>
          <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
          </goals>
            <configuration>
             <files>
             <file>${basedir}/src/main/resources/config.properties</file>
             </files>
            </configuration>
       </execution>
     </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Hi, could you please post the whole pom.xml file?